# How to download publicly accessible files from ieee-dataport through AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

everyone, I want to download a [file](https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/tracking-neurons-moving-and-deforming-brain-dataset) from ieee-portdata through aws s3.

The instruction of ieee-dataport says:

> The dataset is available two ways: as a large all-in-one  0.3 TB  tarball available for download via the web interface; and as a set of individual files that are avalable for browsing or downloading via Amazon S3.

The path of the file is:

> https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/tracking-neurons-moving-and-deforming-brain-dataset

The instruction of ieee-dataport is:

> https://ieee-dataport.org/help/accessing-ieee-dataport-dataset-files-through-amazon-web-services-aws

I have an IEEE account, and I am an IEEE DataPort subscriber.
I have installed AWS CLI and configured it. But when i try to scan the files in the dataport, it always shows:
[image]

How can i download this file from ieee-dataport?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you just can copy the files, not list the bucket. Have you tried `aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname> . --recursive` to copy files to current local folder?

Comment: i have also tried 'cp', it does not work.

Comment: same permission denied issue, or something else?

Comment: yes, same permission denied issue.

Comment: I don't have access to this service, so can't check myself. Maybe have to write to their support?

Comment: yes, i am writing email to them.Thank you very much.